# Watched events not registering as expected

Tags: web3js, events, metamask

I have created a simple contract with one event. I use web3 via MetaMask to watch for these events, however I can see the transactions on Etherscan but the Javascript callback is not being fired for the new event.

Events that happened before page load I can get.

The contract is on [Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x33743a345c0e20f556bf15d19ca12968c47ae4d8#code)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MyContract {
    address creator;
    event HasAccepted(address sender, bool isCreator);

    function MyContract () 
    public 
    {
        creator = msg.sender;
    }

    function accept () 
    public
    {
        bool isCreator = msg.sender == creator;
        HasAccepted(msg.sender, isCreator);
    }
}
```

and associated web3 code below:

```
<html>
  <script>
    var contractAddr = "0x33743a345c0e20f556bf15d19ca12968c47ae4d8";
    var contractAbi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"accept","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"isCreator","type":"bool"}],"name":"HasAccepted","type":"event"}];

    function startApp() {
        var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi);
        var contractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddr);

        document.getElementById('acceptBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            contractInstance.accept({value: 0, gas: 210000}, console.log);
        });

        var event = contractInstance.HasAccepted(function(error, result){
            // Expect to log when click 'Run accept' button
            console.log("HasAccepted", error, result);
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      }
      startApp();
    })
  </script>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="acceptBtn">Run accept</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect that I would see output from the callback given to the 'HasAccepted' event.

Comment: try using `web3.eth.subscribe(type [, options] [, callback]);` as defined  [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#web3-eth-subscribe)

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake that seems like a great addition that will be added in 1.x.x. I am wondering what is the polyfill for https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/0.19.0

Comment: I have also created a question in regards to a polyfill for subscribe. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28928/what-is-the-polyfill-for-subscribe-in-1-x-web3-for-current-version-0-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main issues with your code.
- The method.event() function needs at least one variable: indexed filter or {} if unneeded
- It seeems metamask requires `fromBlock` for event pooling or watching (Sometimes, Metamask syncing to the network can be delayed, not often though)

```
var fromBlock = 1908935;
var contractAddr = "0x33743a345c0e20f556bf15d19ca12968c47ae4d8";
...

    var event = contractInstance.HasAccepted({},{fromBlock:fromBlock},function(error, result){
        // Expect to log when click 'Run accept' button
        console.log("HasAccepted", error, result);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this works! However, strangely the code I posted above also works for me too. I think there could have been an issue in Metamask/web3 that got fixed in the last few days. [v3.11.2](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases/tag/v3.11.2)